# Automatic generation of mock classes for gmock

Tags: c++, unit-testing, visual-studio-2008, googlemock

I am using **gmock** for **unit testing C++ code**. I am not using the **gtest framework**. I am using visual studio 2008's built-in testing framework.

Now my problem is that I have to manually write mock classes for a real class to unit test. For example if I have A class with 5 functions then I have to write MockAClass with 5 functions. Is there any way that these classes are automatically generated.

```
class AClass
{
public:
    virtual int AFunction()
    {
        return 5;
    }
    virtual int AFunctionWithArguments(int x)
    {
        return x;
    }



class MockAClass : public AClass
{
public:
    MOCK_METHOD0(AFucntion, int());
    MOCK_METHOD1(AFunctionWithArgument, int(int x));
};
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There is a tool bundled with the google mock project that will help you do this. However I think the tool requires python to be installed, and I don't know how well it works in a windows environment. I've also found that the generated files sometimes need a little tweak to work perfectly.

Here's the info from the [docs](http://code.google.com/p/googlemock/wiki/ForDummies):

> Tip: If even this is too much work for you, you'll find the
>   gmock_gen.py tool in Google Mock's scripts/generator/ directory
>   (courtesy of the [cppclean](http://code.google.com/p/cppclean/) project) useful. This command-line tool
>   requires that you have Python 2.4 installed. You give it a C++ file
>   and the name of an abstract class defined in it, and it will print the
>   definition of the mock class for you. Due to the complexity of the C++
>   language, this script may not always work, but it can be quite handy
>   when it does. For more details, read the user documentation.

Here is [new localization of this script](https://github.com/google/googletest/tree/master/googlemock/scripts/generator).

Comment: This definitely works on Windows.  I'm at Python 2.7 and it's fine.  Usual caveats apply for hand tweaks...

Comment: This is an outdated answer.

Answer (score 3):

*Disclaimer: I **used to** work at Typemock*

Have you considered using another tool?
Typemock has a tool called [Isolator++](http://www.typemock.com/isolatorpp-product-page) that do not need you to write "mocking classes".

```
TEST_F(IsolatorTests, SomeTest) 
{
      AClass* fakeclass = FAKE(AClass);
      WHEN_CALLED(fakeclass->AFunction()).Return(10);

      ASSERT_EQ(10, fakeclass.AFunction()); 
}
```

You can learn more about it at this [about page](http://www.typemock.com/what-is-isolator-pp)

Comment: i have read about isolator++. but that is not free. you have to get license for that.

Comment: @DrorHelper Probably worth a disclaimer that you used to work for Typemock. (Not that that makes it a bad product etc, but its good to disclose such potential sources of bias).

Comment: Moq (http://code.google.com/p/moq/) is a free library for c# unit testing. isolator++ is same for c++ but they are asking money. i want a free library. dont have money to spent on that. i buy isolator++ for 600 dollars while the application i am making is of 200 dollar. doesnt make any sense to use isolator++.

Comment: @Michael Anderson I would add the disclaimer although I don't see the relevnace - since I no longer work there

Comment: @fhnaseer the sad truth is that usually it's a matter of trade-off either spend your money or your time (equals money). I wish I knew of a free (preferably open source) tool that can help you but I'm not aware of one. Another option is to use a manager C++ wrapper and use .NET (free) mocking framework but it seems like a lot of work.

Comment: somebody told me that there are scripts which can do this, any idea about that,